# Taking the average for regression

Tags: regression

Let's assume you conduct a survey about some topic. After that, you want to analyze the responses and perform a regression. For example:

- IV: Age
- Percentage that every traveled to country X

When I plot all responses the, chart is messy with responses all over the place. When I plot the average response per age it looks similar to the chart below.

I would now like to run a regression to predict the response per age category. I would have usually taken all the responses and use them for my regression. However, in the book "Regression and other stories" I saw the following chart where they took averages. Is it reasonable to take the mean response per age?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited my request. Please let me know it it's clear now or if I should adjust it further

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy